# In linq how dynamically pass table and column name

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I want to write an dynamic linq where i send table and column name this query return me the max row number of the table .

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(intProductCode) + 1, 1) AS intProductCode FROM tblProductInfo
```

Above is my T-SQL syntax.I want same output from the linq how to

If i write this bellow syntax get same out put but here i can not set **table and column name**

```
this.Context.tblProductInfos.Max(p=>p.intProductCode)
```

How to set table and column name on linq which return max row number of this table.

Comment: it is poor form to ask a linq-to-sql question, accept a linq-to-sql answer, then (two years later) ask in comments a linq-to-entity's question in comments of another answer, and accept that answer based on comments.  It is better to ask separate questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ isn't the answer to everything. Sure, you *can* query the data-context to get all this information, but you're going to be doing a *lot* of work (either reflection or mapping, plus building an `Expression`), simply for the sql generator to reverse *everything* to get back TSQL. It would be a *lot* simpler to just build the TSQL (making sure to white-list the table/column names to prevent injection) and use [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx).

For example:

```
string tsql = string.Format(
      "SELECT ISNULL(MAX([{0}]) + 1, 1) AS [{0}] FROM [{1}]",
       colName, tableName);

int max = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<int>(tsql).First();
```

Also; if `intProductCode` is the `IDENTITY`, you might want to look at [`IDENT_CURRENT(tableName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx), which is *much* more efficient than `MAX`.

Comment: Marc Gravell how to use this sql syntax in linq.SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('tableName') AS Current_Identity. i replace string tsql with your syntax but it's not working show me error message "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: IDENT_CURRENT returns a `decimal`, IIRC. Try `SELECT CAST(IDENT_CURRENT('tableName') as int) as Current_Identity`

Comment: Marc Gravell thanks for reply, In EF(Entity framework) there is no method ExecuteQuery(),will you please tell me how to execute your sql syntax in EF .Thanks for all

Comment: @shamim [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.103).aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
int GetMax<T>(DataContext dc, Expression<Func<T, int>> selector)
{
  int result = dc.GetTable<T>().Max(selector);
  return result;
}
```

Called like this:

```
int maxId = GetMax<Customer>(myDC, c => c.CustomerId);
```

---

On the other hand, you could just use IDENTITY columns in the database.  Then you don't have to +1, and you don't have to deal with collisions from multiple connections.

Comment: David B thanks for reply,will you please tell me how to set where in your syntax ,suppose want to set WHERE City='Berlin'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you don't really need any dynamic linq here.

You should just stop thinking in terms of SQL magic strings like table and column names. L2S allows you to write queries in strong type manner. Examine the code you have already written.

```
this.Context.tblProductInfos.Max(p=>p.intProductCode)
```

1. `tblProductInfos` is actually a strong typed 'table name'
2. `p=>p.intProductCode` is an expression to get 'column name'

Everything is nice and clear. No magic strings required. That's what ORM for.

Comment: i need a common method who return me the table  max row.very much time  I need to call this method .

Comment: You do already have this method for all IEnumerables. 
Why do you think 
`Helper.Max("tableName", "columnName")` syntax is better than 'context.TableName.Max(x=>x.ColumnName)'?

Comment: The problem here is that the code as posted doesn't help if you don't know the table-name / column-name at compile-time.